# How do i check whether the curent branch is a tag release?

Tags: git, branch

I am trying for automation in circleci. For that I need to check whether the current branch in master is a tag release or not.

```
git log -1 --pretty=%B | grep "Tag version release [0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]_[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+"
```

Using the above command I am able to read the log.

But what i need is the tag: 
commit sld1kf3ja5ls6kj7gi8rogaeknvaerglreun (HEAD -> master, tag: v1.2.3_0.10.101, origin/master, origin/HEAD)

Comment: "the current branch in master is a tag release or not" - what i meant was the current branch is a tag or not ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: consider using `git tag --points-at`, but be aware of its limitations.

#### Long

The current *branch* is never a *tag*, by definition.

In Git, the *current branch* is the branch name stored in the special name `HEAD`.  Running `git checkout` or, since Git 2.23, `git switch`, allows you to pick a branch by name and set that branch as the current branch.  To make branch *B* the *current* branch, Git will:

- replace the current commit with the *tip* commit of branch *B* if necessary (or do nothing at all if the current commit *is* the tip comimt of branch *B*);<sup>1</sup> then
- write the branch's name into the name `HEAD`.

So now, after `git checkout master` or `git checkout develop`, the current *branch* is `master` or `develop`, respectively.  The current *commit* is the last commit of the named branch.

If, however, you issue the command `git checkout v1.2.3_0.10.101`—or the equivalent `git switch` command—the *name* you requested is a *tag name* and not a *branch name*.  Git *will not* write the tag name into `HEAD`.  Instead, Git resolves the name into a commit hash ID.  Then, Git *detaches HEAD* by making sure that `HEAD` *no longer contains any name at all*.  Instead, Git will:

- replace the current commit with the selected commit if necessary—as before, if the *current commit* is the *selected* commit, nothing is necessary here; then
- write the *raw commit hash ID* into the name `HEAD`.

The effect is that you are no longer on any branch at all.

> I need to check whether the current branch in master is a tag release or not.

The phrase *current branch in master* is simply meaningless.

Every commit has a unique hash ID (it's never `sld1kf3j...` as the set of letters and digits only includes `0-9` and `a-f`, so it's more like `badf00d` or `cafebabe` or `deadbeef`, but longer).  That one hash ID means *that* commit, and no other commit, ever.

Meanwhile, every *name* holds one hash ID.  Multiple names may hold the same hash ID.  So if you are on a branch because you checked one out, there is a commit.  If you checked out a tag, there is a commit, but you're no longer on a branch.

You can check whether the *current commit* has one or more *names* as well. That's what the decoration in `git log` does, for instance.  But it may have many names:

```
$ git log -1
commit <hash> (master, develop, feature, tag: v1.0, tag: beta)
```

This tells you that the *current commit* is the given hash and that there are two tags and three branch names, all of which would select that commit.  The lack of `HEAD ->` here implies that while this is the current commit, we probably did not select it via a branch name.  (But `git checkout --detach master` or `git checkout --detach develop` would result in this same situation, so maybe we *did* use a branch name and simply *also* used the `--detach` option.)

The only really-sure-fire way to be sure that we arrived at this particular commit by some particular `git checkout` or `git switch` command is to remember the `git checkout` or `git switch` command we ran.  If your system does that, use that.  If it doesn't, there is no sure-fire way to deal with this.<sup>2</sup>

You can, however, check whether one or more tag names point directly to the current commit:

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

would, in the above example, spill out the two names `v1.0` and `beta`.  Note that it would do this even if we got here by running `git checkout master`, though.

If `git tag --points-at` prints *no* names, no tags point to the current commit.

To tell whether `HEAD` contains a branch name right now, consider using:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD
```

which prints the full name of the branch if `HEAD` contains a branch name:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

or produces an error if `HEAD` is detached:

```
$ git checkout --detach master
[messages]
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

Note that `--points-at` was new for `git tag` in Git version 1.7.10, so if your Git is older than this, you would need to upgrade.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *replace the current commit* step consists of, in effect:

- removing the current commit's files from Git's index and your work-tree, then
- copying to Git's index and your work-tree, the files from the selected commit.

The selected commit is now the current commit, thanks to this "rip out all the files from commit X and insert all the files from commit Y instead" action.  Note that both `git checkout` and `git switch` are careful to rip out only files that are "cleanly saved" in the current commit: the checkout or switch will fail, with an error, if this would lose data.  You can, of course, force the switch with `-f` / `--force`.

<sup>2</sup>If reflogs are enabled, the reflog has much of the information you might want.  But the points-at method is probably better.